# Using templates via dotnet-new VS "dotnet new"

Tags: servicestack

Trying to get back into ServiceStack, and see a lot has happened on the .NET Core end.

Now it seems that the ServiceStack "native" CLI (`dotnet-new`) is the most up-to-date one, and it's the one referenced in the documentation, but I can't help but wonder why then do we have the following repo:

https://github.com/NetCoreApps/templates

It seems to provide the same functionality, but through the standard `dotnet new` command shipped with the Core SDK.

I would say that using the standard `dotnet new` command is a bit more intuitive to use, and creates less confusion, but seeing as how there has been no commits there for 7 months, I'm a bit unsure.

Should we use `dotnet-new`, and if so, any reason why that is preferable to integrating with the .NET Core SDK's `dotnet new` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**dotnet new** is .NET Core's built-in templating system, as it's inefficient for creating and maintaining templates ServiceStack uses its own [dotnet-new](http://docs.servicestack.net/dotnet-new) tool which is able to create templates directly from versioned GitHub repositories which automatically uses the latest published version of each template without needing to update local packages and makes available new templates discoverable as soon as they're available without needing to manually install them.

E.g. All the .NET Templates published to the following organizations are immediately available when running `dotnet-new` without arguments:

- https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates
- https://github.com/NetFrameworkTemplates
- https://github.com/NetFrameworkCoreTemplates

> $ dotnet-new

[image]

Among other features it can create Templates from any published GitHub project Release or from a link to a `.zip`.

Because the templates are frequently updated to keep in sync with the latest JS Frameworks we needed to use a better solution for being able to deliver updates to the latest templates. Eventually after premier JS SPA frameworks have matured we'll also publish sync versions to .NET Core's **dotnet new** tool. But to use the latest ServiceStack templates use ServiceStack's `dotnet-new` tool available in `@servicestack/cli` npm package:

```
$ npm install -g @servicestack/cli
```